# Confused about inductive proof that any Prüfer sequence has a corresponding tree

Tags: graph-theory, induction, trees

> Let $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2})$ be a sequence of integers with $1 \leq a_i \leq n$. Prove that $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2})$ is the Prufer sequence of some tree with vertex set $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

The proof is a proof by induction, and is as follows: Let $k$ be the smallest integer in $\{1, \dots, n\}$ that does not appear in $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2})$. Then by the inductive hypothesis, $(a_2, \dots, a_{n-2})$ is a Prüfer sequence of a tree with vertex set $\{1, \dots, k-1, k+1, \dots, n\}$. We form a tree $T$ by adding the vertex $k$ and connecting it to $a_1$. Then $T$ has Prufer sequence $(a_1, \dots, a_{n-2})$.

I'm confused about a few things about this proof:

1. If $n$ appears in $(a_2, \dots, a_{n-2})$, then we cannot apply the inductive hypothesis as there would be a restriction on $a_i \leq n-1$. How does this work?
2. When applying the inductive hypothesis, doesn't the vertex set of the generated tree need to be of form $(1, \dots, n-1)$? Why can we arbitrarily choose its vertex set to be $\{1, \dots, k-1, k+1, \dots, n\}$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood a point: the induction is on the number of vertices (which is $n$, and becomes $n-1$ once you've removed a vertex).

Comment: Indeed you might not (and probably won't) choose $a_1=n$, so you're going to get $(a_2,a_3 ... ,a_n)$ a subset of $\{ 1,...n\}$ which might include $n$, but that won't be a problem for Prüfer sequence: what matters is the ordering of the vertices, and not the exact label.

Comment: @thibo I don't quite understand your 2nd comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: What I'm clumsily saying is that you can get a Prüfer sequence for an arbitrary choice of label for your tree, as long as 1- the vertex set is fixed 2- the ordering is fixed
Hence, if you have a subset of $\{1,...,k-1,k+1,...,n \}$ of size $n-3$, it uniquely describes a tree with vertices $\{1,...,k-1,k+1,...,n \}$.
What you've got to do is apply the usual Prüfer decoding, except you don't use vertex $k$.

Comment: @thibo I've reached a similar conclusion as you, but is it possible to map the vertices of this tree with vertices $\{1, \dots, k-1, k+1, \dots, n\}$ back to a tree with vertices $\{1, \dots, n-1\}$ and vice versa, such that the Prüfer sequence remains the same? Nothing I try seems to work, and finding this map would solve issue (2) in the original question: after applying the inductive hypothesis we can map the generated tree to a tree with vertex set $\{1, \dots, k-1, k+1, \dots, n\}$.

Comment: For instance if your sequence is  $(4, 4, 4, 5)$ (and your vertex-set $V=\{1,...,6\}$,
1) $1$ is the smallest index belonging to $V$ missing in the sequence, so you add this vertex, with an edge to $4$
you get the sequence $(4,4,5)$ with vertex-set $V'=\{2,...,6\}$
2) $2$ is the smallest index belonging to $V'$ missing in the sequence, so you add this vertex, with an edge to $4$
you get the sequence $(4,5)$ with vertex-set $V'=\{3,...,6\}$
3) $3$ is the smallest index belonging to $V'$ missing in the sequence, ...

Comment: (once the Prüfer encoding becomes the empty list, you're left with 2 elements that have not been removed from the vertex-set yet, and you just need to add an edge between these 2

Comment: Yep I got all that! Is there really no way to perform induction on the fixed vertex set $(1, \dots, n)$? The question I'm working on is looking for a bijection between Prüfer sequences of length $n-2$ and trees of vertex set $(1, \dots n)$.

Comment: Is is a bijection this way (since you start from any sequence). If you want, you could do a relabeling of the graph at each step but frankly this would but a lot of work for little use. Do you want me to give an extended example as an answer of the original question?

Comment: @thibo I think the relabelling is what I'm after; I'm not very sure how to express it rigorously in this context. An elaboration of the relabelling as an answer would be great!

Comment: @Jan: Vertices $1,\ldots,k$ retain their labels; the label of each of the remaining vertices is reduced by $1$. You do this both for the tree and for the Prüfer sequence. The induction hypothesis then gives you the tree on vertices labelled $1,\ldots,n-1$. Increase each of the labels in $\{k,\ldots,n-1\}$ by $1$, add vertex $k$, and connect it to $a_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: @Jan: You’re very welcome; glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is the decoding of a Prüfer sequence.

I'm going to describe this decoding on one example: start with the Prüfer sequence $P=(5,2,1,6)$ (hence on vertex-set $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$).

We are going to construct the edge list $T$ of the corresponding tree.

- The least number appearing in $V$ but not in $P$ is $3$, so we add the edge $\{3,5\}$ to  $T$, and remove $5$ from $P$ and $3$ from $V$. $T$ is currently $\{ \{3,5\} \}$.
- We now have $P=(2,1,6)$ (hence on vertex-set $V=\{1,2,4,5,6\}$.
  The least number appearing in $V$ but not in $P$ is $4$, so we add the edge $\{4,2\}$ to  $T$, and remove $2$ from $P$ and $5$ from $V$. $T$ is now $\{ \{3,5\};\{2,4\} \}$.
- We now have $P=(1,6)$ and remaning vertices are $V=\{1,2,5,6\}$.
  The least number appearing in $V$ but not in $P$ is $2$, so we add the edge $\{2,1\}$ to  $T$, and remove $1$ from $P$ and $2$ from $V$. $T$ is now $\{ \{3,5\};\{2,4\} ; \{1,4\} \}$.
- Now $P=(6)$ a nd $V=\{1,5,6\}$.
  The least number appearing in $V$ but not in $P$ is $1$, so we add the edge $\{1,6\}$ to  $T$, and remove $6$ from $P$ and $1$ from $V$. $T$ is now $\{ \{3,5\};\{2,4\} ; \{1,4\} ; \{1,6\} \}$.
- Now $P$ is empty, and vertices $5$ and $6$ are left in $V$, so we add the edge $\{5,6\}$ to $T$, which is finally full (size $6-1 = 5$) and equal to $\{ \{3,5\};\{2,4\} ; \{1,4\} ; \{1,6\} ; \{5,6\} \}$.

This can be used to show that Prüfer encoding is a bijection from trees with $n$ vertices to sequences in $\{1,...,n\}^{n-2}$ because:

1- from any sequence $P$ in  $\{1,...,n\}^{n-2}$ you get a tree $T$ on $n$ vertices

2- the Prüfer sequence of $T$ is $P$ (we haven't quite proved this but is holds, you can test this on the example)